# Handling Null reference exception

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am trying to insert following into my code.

```
Public ReadOnly Property SelectedCustomer() As Customer
    Get
        If lstCustomers.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
            ' Return the selected customer
            Return CType(objCustomers(lstCustomers.SelectedIndex), Customer)
        End If
    End Get
End Property
```

But while saving following warning occures.

**Property 'SelectedCustomer' doesn't return a value on all code paths. A null reference exception could occur at run time when the result is used.**

How to resolve this? Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when lstCustomer.SelectedIndex = -1? 
You are currently not returning anything. Which is why you are getting the not return on all paths message.

A simple solution

```
Public ReadOnly Property SelectedCustomer() As Customer
    Get
        If lstCustomers.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
            ' Return the selected customer
            Return CType(objCustomers(lstCustomers.SelectedIndex), Customer)
        End If

        Return Nothing
    End Get
End Property
```

The problem with this is you still have to handle for Nothing when reading this property.
You could also return a new instance of Customer, but once again, you need to handle that on the other end.